# SyntaxError при чтении атрибутов константного числа

Tags: python

Такой код:

```
1.real
```

выведет

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.real
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Но такой код:

```
var = 1
var.real

int('1').real

getattr(1, 'real')
```

отработает нормально

---

Cо строкой все работает ожидаемо:

```
's'.islower()
```

---

В чем проблема? Почему читать атрибуты у константного числа можно только через костили, и нельзя по нормальному?

P.S: Я не смог найти каких либо  статей/вопросов по этому поводу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Разбирая такое выражение,

```
1.real
```

интерпретатор, увидев после единицы точку, ожидает, что это вещественное число, после которого ни с того ни с сего идёт слово `real`. Возникает синтаксическая ошибка.

Например, в следующих выражениях нет двойственности, и ошибки не возникает:

```
1..real  // 1.0
1.0.real  // 1.0
1 .real  // 1
(1).real  // 1
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11802242/7485582)

Answer (score 3):

Просто пробел добавьте:

```
>>> 1 .real
1
```

Вариант с пробелом распознаётся как обращение к атрибуту целого числа:

```
$ python -m tokenize -e <<<'1 .real'                               
1,0-1,1:            NUMBER         '1'      
1,2-1,3:            DOT            '.'      
1,3-1,7:            NAME           'real'   
1,7-1,8:            NEWLINE        '\n'     
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

Вариант без пробела распознаётся как  число, за которым сразу имя идёт :

```
$ python -m tokenize -e  <<<'1.real'                                         
1,0-1,2:            NUMBER         '1.'     
1,2-1,6:            NAME           'real'   
1,6-1,7:            NEWLINE        '\n'     
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

Последнее является синтаксической ошибкой в Питоне:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.parse('1.real')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    1.real
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

С пробелом нет ошибки:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('1 .real', 'eval').body[0])
"Expr(value=Attribute(value=Num(n=1), attr='real', ctx=Load()))"
```